# Perl: How do you insert numbers after grouping variable?

Tags: regex, perl

I've got the following substitution in a Perl one liner:

```
perl -pi.bak -e 's/(.*?\t.*?\t.*?\t.*?\t.*?\t.*?\t.*?\t.*?\t.*?\t)/$123424977\t/g if $. <= 200'
```

The problem is that I want to insert the number 23424977 after the text that is captured by the grouped regex `(.*?\t.*?\t.*?\t.*?\t.*?\t.*?\t.*?\t.*?\t.*?\t)`.

But Perl thinks I'm referring to group $123424977!  How do I tell Perl I want group $1 and to insert the text 23424977 after that?

Comment: The whole example could be simplified to something like: `$s = 1; print "$s2"` vs. `$s = 1; print "${s}2"`.

Answer (score 5):

You can use curly braces to unambiguously delimit the variable-name — `${1}` instead of `$1`:

```
perl -pi.bak -e 's/(.*?\t.*?\t.*?\t.*?\t.*?\t.*?\t.*?\t.*?\t.*?\t)/${1}23424977\t/g if $. <= 200'
```

Answer (score 3):

You could also rewrite your regex in a more readable/elegant way:

```
perl -pi.bak -e 's/((?:.*?\t){9})/${1}23424977\t/g if $. <= 200'
```

Answer (score 2):

use the following syntax

`${1}234567`

Answer (score 2):

One could use the `\K` flag to do away with the `$1` requirement altogether:

```
s/(?:.*?\t){9}\K/23424977/g
```

But isn't there a more Perlish way to do this using autosplit? There is more than one way to do it, but some are more convenient than others:

```
$ perl -F/\t/-api.bak -e 'splice@F,9,0,23423977 if $. < 200; $_ = join "\t", @F;'
```

Answer (score 1):

surround with {}

```
perl -pi.bak -e 's/(.*?\t.*?\t.*?\t.*?\t.*?\t.*?\t.*?\t.*?\t.*?\t)/${1}23424977\t/g if $. <= 200'
                                                               _____^ ^
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way: don't use a group at all and make your substitution be `$&23424977\t` (`$&` refers to the full text matched by the left part of the `s///` operator)