# Perl: How do you insert numbers after grouping variable?

Tags: regex, perl

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Perl: How do you insert numbers after grouping variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8592523/perl-how-do-you-insert-numbers-after-grouping-variable)

I have the following perl one liner:

```
perl -pi.bak -e 's/(.*?\t.*?\t.*?\t.*?\t.*?\t.*?\t.*?\t.*?\t.*?\t)/$123424977\t/g if $. <= 200'
```

The problem is that I want to insert the number 23424977 after the grouped regex `(.*?\t.*?\t.*?\t.*?\t.*?\t.*?\t.*?\t.*?\t.*?\t)`.

But Perl thinks I'm referring to group $123424977 and doesn't recognize I mean $1 and that 23424977 is the number I want to insert afterwards.  How can I correct this?

Comment: don't ask the same question multiple times. If you aren't getting the answers you want, either make your question clearer, make comments on answers, or allow your own mindset to accept something you weren't expecting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

simply refer to the $1 capture group with surrounding braces: `${1}`:

```
perl -pi.bak -e 's/(.*?\t.*?\t.*?\t.*?\t.*?\t.*?\t.*?\t.*?\t.*?\t)/${1}23424977\t/g if $. <= 200'
```